# Changing Value of a column fetched from database, before displaying it on jsp in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate framework and am working on a very simple structure.

Scenario:

I have 2 tables, say A and B. A column in A is foreign key in A and primary Key in B.
Now I want to change the value of that particular column in table A to a corresponding value of another column in Table B .... just for displaying in JSP not actually in db itself.

I want to do this because in table A I have a code and in table B I have the corresponding value, and I want to display value not the code.

How can I achieve this? (maybe Joins?)

Here is my current code:

Hibernate Connection:

```
public class HibernateConnection {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Class where query is executed:

```
public class contactQuery {

public List<contactPersistence> list(String whereClause){
    Session session = HibernateConnection.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<contactPersistence> contactList = null;
    try {
        contactList = (List<contactPersistence>) session.createQuery(" from contactPersistence " + whereClause).list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        session.getTransaction().rollback();

    }
    return contactList;
}

}
```

Persistence Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contacts")

public class contactPersistence implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8767337896773261247L;

private String Contact_Code;
private String Name;
private String Customer_Code;
//other columns//

@Id
@GeneratedValue

@Column (name="Job_Title")
public String getJob_Title() {
    return Job_Title;
}

public void setJob_Title(String Job_Title) {
    this.Job_Title = Job_Title;
}
....
....
//other columns defined similarly
....
....

}
```

Here I want to replace the customer_code with the name of the customer from another table.
I tried changing the value in persistence class (in the setter method of the column) but that changes the value in db itself by an update command. That is not what I want.

Any suggestion is welcome.

And I have provided information that I thought would be enough, if it is not, please comment.

**EDIT:**

This is the jsp where I am displaying data:

```
    <s:iterator value="contactDetail" var="contactTable">
        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="Name"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Job_Title"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Email"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Phone"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Mobile"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Fax"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Address"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="Notes"/></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
```

contactDetail and contactTable come from the action class:

```
private List<contactPersistence> contactDetail;

public List<contactPersistence> getContactDetail() {
    return contactDetail;
}

public void setContactDetail(List<contactPersistence> contactDetail) {
    this.contactDetail = contactDetail;
}

private String contactTable;

public String getContactTable() {
    return contactTable;
}

public void setContactTable(String contactTable) {
    this.contactTable = contactTable;
}

private contactQuery contactQuery;

///////////////////contact detail is populated here//////////
this.contactDetail=contactQuery.list(deWhereClause);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. You got two things wrong.

1. If the field is supposed to hold a code, let it hold a code, not a name. Treating your fields like this will lead to unreadable and unmaintainable code. If getCode() returns the name, getName() returns the address and getAddress() returns the phone number, you and your coworkers will quickly lose all their hairs.
2. A contact should not have a field `customerCode` of type `String`. It should have a field `customer` of type `Customer`, where `Customer` is the Hibernate entity representing a customer. This is called an association. If a customer has several contacts, it is a ManyToOne association. If it just has one, it's a OneToOne association. This way, to get the customer's name, you would just use `contact.getCustomer().getName()`.

You should read the [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/).

Side note: not respecting the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) makes your code hard to read. Class names must start with an uppercase letter, and variable and method with a lowercase. None of them should contain an underscore (example : ContactPersistence, jobTitle)

Comment: Thanks for answering JB!!

1.) I think you got something wrong if you are saying the 1st point, because that is the way I have done it, getCode returns code and getName returns name etc. I just wanted to **display** name instead of code.

2.) I believe this should work out, thanks a lot. I will read about and try out association. Thanks for the reference manual link.

Comment: As for naming convention, I know its wrong here, but I thought that variables representing columns should be exactly same as the column names in the database that is why I wrote them like that. Is it not necessary ?

Comment: Hi JB, I read about associations, but am not able to figure out how can I modify my contactDetails list (which I use in jsp for displaying details in a table) to include a column of customer name instead of customer code. I included a many-to-one annotation in the contactPersistence class and also created a customerPersistence class object with getter and setter. But still how will I access customer name in jsp....please advise.. I am really stuck up.

Comment: Finally got through... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stuck on same kind of problem, here is the link that helped from beginning to end on associations.

http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/getting-started/index.php

It is a good 'step by step' article for beginners.

You can then move on to hibernate reference manual for more detail.
(This is what I did!!)